# How i play Mp3 from server from avaudioplayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am new in iPhone,Anyone tell me please how i play audio uploaded on server.
in my application some songs are from local and some others are from Server,Locally i play songs successfully but how i play a audio file from server from AVAudioplayer.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error:):

```
AVAudioPlayer *player = [AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfUrl:urlToAudioResource];
[player play];
```

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Answer (score 1):

AVAudioPlayer plays file when it loads. To stream audio you should try use AVPlayer. It can play audio from web servers without UI freezing.